# Is it possible to set up independent Entra ID environments in the same tenant?

Tags: microsoft-entra-id, azure-entra-id

I'm looking to create Azure AD hands-on content. We plan to issue accounts to trainees and practice creating users and groups.

Is there a way to ensure that only the account information is exposed when a trainee logs in within the same tenant? (Independent environment for each user)

For example, when students A and B log in, User A cannot see User B's information, and User A must be able to create a user named User B.

Is there a way to satisfy the above conditions?